Laravel relationships with extended models
I've got a requirement for a set of models with the same database table, but they need to implement certain methods in a different way. Given a set of classes like this:
class Item {
    protected $table = 'items';
}
interface SubItem {
    public function foo();
}
class ItemA extends Item implements SubItem {
    public function __construct($attributes) {
        $attributes['type'] = 'ItemA'; 
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
    public function foo(){
        do_abc();
    }
}
class ItemB extends Item implements SubItem {
    public function __construct($attributes) {
        $attributes['type'] = 'ItemB'; 
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
    public function foo(){
        do_def();
    }
}
class ItemC extends Item implements SubItem {
    public function __construct($attributes) {
        $attributes['type'] = 'ItemC'; 
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
    public function foo(){
        do_ghi();
    }
}
class Owner {
    public function items() {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}

All works fine until I try to fetch the items() relationship. The resulting instances are cast to the Item class, and I'm unable to call the foo() function.
It seems like I should be able to declare Item as abstract and use the type column to have the relationship return a collection of ItemA, ItemB, and ItemC instances but this is clearly not the case. I may want to add an arbitrary number of additional child classes in the future. Does Laravel have a way to make this work?
Alternatives considered:

Polymorphic relationships, which don't seem to address this situation
Add the method to the Item class and run different code based on the instance type, which is very messy
Add relationships for every type and have a 'fake' relationship method collect them all behind the scenes, which is slightly less messy but doesn’t seem possible


The simple answer is no, you need more information in order for the model to be cast to a specific instance. Is there an attribute/field which specifies what instance of Item it should be?

how do you know, after saving each item to the database, what exact type they were? And yes a polymorphic relation would be better since you would store owner_id: 1, item_id:1234, item_type:App\Models\ItemA

@JonMenard yes there is a column indicating the type of model it should be

what you are trying to do looks like a good candidate for a state pattern implementation, i.e. based on some conditions the method on a model will do different things. It may also work by changing the items method shown, but you should add how you would use the different classes...

@suxgri not sure what you mean by 'how you would use the different classes'. I need to end up with a collection of the different item types, and then be able to call the interface method on each of them.

One of the answers gave me the idea of overriding the model's methods; I came up with this, which is fairly minimal and works well:
class Item extends Model
{
    public function __construct($attributes = [])
    {
        $attributes['type'] = static::class;
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
    
    public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null): Model
    {
        $model = parent::newFromBuilder($attributes, $connection);
    
        return class_exists($model->type) && !$model instanceof $model->type
            ? (new $model->type)->newFromBuilder($model->getAttributes(), $connection)
            : $model;
    }
}

This allows any number of additional models to be added without having to touch the base class again.

If you have a column indicating the type of model in it should be, try using the newFromBuilder method to create a new instance of the Item as the correct type. I am not sure which field specifies the model type in your case, but I will assume it is type:
class Item extends Model {
    protected $table = 'items';

    protected static $typeMapping = [
        'item_a' => ItemA::class,
        'item_b' => ItemB::class,
        'item_c' => ItemC::class,
    ];

    // Override the newFromBuilder method
    public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
    {
        // Map the 'type' value to a specific class
        $class = static::$typeMapping[$attributes->type] ?? self::class;

        $model = (new $class)->newInstance((array) $attributes, true);
        $model->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes);
        $model->fireModelEvent('retrieved', false);
        return $model;
    }
}


This doesn't make any sense. The newInstance() method is used to return a newly instantiated model; with this in place there is no way to get the existing model instance pulled from the database.

What do you mean there is no way to pull an existing model instance, the attributes array will contain all the information about the model, and load that into the correct class.

Before implementing this override I was getting 5 Item instances. After I tried it I got 5 empty ItemA, ItemB, ItemC instances with only the type field set (because it's set in the constructor of each class.) This code also misses important functionality from Model::newFromBuilder() like firing events.

The $attributes array passed to this method is whatever has been passed to the constructor or static methods like Model::create(). It's not the model's full set of attributes.

There seems to be a bug with the attributes being set, I added $model->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes); to my solution, which should fix it

i would try this quickly:
class Owner {
    public function items($className) {
        return $this->hasMany($className);
    }
}

and then the client would call it like this:
$shouldBeInstanceOfItemA= Owner::items(ItemA::class)->first();

and now the correct foo method could be called on it, as an alternative as mentioned in the comment of the original post the state pattern should do it.
EDIT:
based on the additional information in the comments below, the solution is to adopt a simplified version of the state pattern:
class Owner {
    public function items() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }

    public function state(): SubItem
    {
        return match($this->yourDbColumn){
            'value1'=> new itemA($this),
            'value2'=> new itemB($this),
            'value3'=> new itemC($this),
            default => throw ...,
        };
    }
}

Your ItemA, B and C classes now will look like:
class ItemA implements SubItem{
    //constructor takes the item model
    //foo method does its things
}

the client code does this:
$items = $owner->items()->where(...)->get();//Items collection

foreach($items as $item){
    $item->state()->foo();//foo called on the ItemA, B or C
}


The idea is to transparently use the items() relationship method to get all the instances together. This would not be much of an improvement over just having 3 relationship methods.

ok, if i understand, you want to call Owner::items()->get(); and you want a collection containing the ItemA, B and C classes, if so you will need a mechanism to assign the db row to ItemA, B and C right ?

Yes. I can easily create an accessor to get a property like $owner->items but I need the relationship method to do like $owner->items()->where(...)->get() that will return all matching item types

ok so itemA, B and C will be based on some database value, e.g. you have a status column and based on the value the row will belong to ItemA, B or C ?

Correct, the question was updated to indicate this.
